# Inline style aspect ratio not working in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is this an issue with React inline styling? I have a Crop component where I want to change the crop view based on the aspect ratio of the pic coming in.

When I pass the variables to Crop:

```
<Crop width={"200"} height={"100"}
```

I have in my `Crop.js` component:

```
<div style={{aspectRatio: `calc(${width}px / ${height}px)` }}>
</div>
```

But the changes don't show. However, when I write a regular aspect ratio with integers (i.e., 1/2) it does change. Is there a way to accomplish this the way I'm trying to? It'll help me with multiple components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`aspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) expect a value of  type [`<ratio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ratio), and you are giving it a `calc`. The example below works:

```
export default function App() {
  const width = 200;
  const height = 60;
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        aspectRatio: width / height,
        background: "red"
      }}
    ></div>
  );
}
```

Also, pass them as numbers instead of strings:

```js
<Crop width={200} height={100}
```

[image]